# Operator >> for a char pointer wrapper

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, iostream

Because i'm not allowed to use std::string for an assignment i'm using a Custom class called CharString as a wrapper for those cases where i cannot initialize it myself.

The class looks like this:

```
struct CharString {
    char* str;
    CharString() : str() {}  // Initialize NULL
    ~CharString() { free(str); }
    // Conversions to be usable with C functions
    operator char**() { return &str; }
    operator char*() { return str; }
};
```

However i get the following error when i want to use >> on it.

```
binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'utils::CharString' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

How can i overload the operator `>>` ?

```
CharString operator>>(std::istream& is) {
    is >> str;
    return *this;
};
```

I tried the above but that still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to overload the stream extraction operator is to provide a friend function with this general form:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, MyObjectType& object) {
    // read all the data you need to construct an object.
    //
    // Then:
    if (in) { // Read succeeded! Update object.
        // Build a new object of the appropriate type.
        MyObjectType theOneIRead(basedOnTheDataIRead);

        // Swap the object you were given as input for the one you
        // just read. This way, if the read completely succeeds, you
        // update the rhs, and if the read failed, nothing happens.
        std::swap(object, theOneIRead);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Notice that this function's signature is going to be different than the one that you've written.

You'll need to take care of the logic associated with reading characters one at a time from the stream and building some sort of temporary buffer to hold them. That's not trivial and is one of the reasons why it's so nice that we have a `std::string` type packaged with the library. But other than that, following the template below should give you what you want.

Independently - your struct currently has a destructor, but has no copy constructor, move constructor, or assignment operator. Typically, you'd want to also implement those functions alongside the destructor, since otherwise copying your object will end up doing a shallow copy of the pointer and leading to memory problems when two independent objects try to free the same pointer.

Additionally, since this is C++, consider using `new[]` and `delete[]` rather than `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: I assume i need to place this in my CharString struct but this gives me errors aswell: `cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone`  when using istream only or `too many parameters for this operator function` when I use both parameters.

Comment: This should be a friend function rather than a member function. Make sure to declare it outside of your class, and then add a friend declaration for it inside the class.